# Want to remove style src unsafe inline from application

Tags: java, http, content-security-policy

I'm trying to mitigate XSS attacks by setting the Content-Security-Policy header but Chrome keeps throwing an error:

Refused to execute inline event handler because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'nonce-Njg3MGUxNzkyMjViNDZkN2I3YTM3MDAzY2M0MjUxZGEzZmFhNDU0OGZjNDExMWU5OTVmMmMwMTg4NTA3ZmY4OQ=='". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

Here's my Content-Security-Policy header:

Dont want to include style src unsafe-inline in my application while removing its throwing error

```
        httpResponse.setHeader(
                "Content-Security-Policy",
                "default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' data:;"
                        + "style-src 'self' fonts.googleapis.com 'sha256-CwE3Bg0VYQOIdNAkbB/Btdkhul49qZuwgNCMPgNY5zw=';" + "base-uri 'self' data:;"
                        + "frame-src 'self' * data:;" + "connect-src 'self' * data:;"
                        + "font-src 'self' fonts.gstatic.com https://cdn.predix-ui.com data:;"
                        + "frame-ancestors 'self' data:");
        chain.doFilter(request, httpResponse);
```

Comment: Any help please where i should not get the style src volubility test. 
Any modification i need to do for style src unsafe inline

Answer (score 0):

This message complains against scripts (not styles):

`Refused to execute inline event handler`

And there is no setup for the `script-src` in your illustrated code snippet.

Arrange allowed types / sources (especially, related to scripts content) to resolve this issue.

Comment: should not see style src unsafe inline what is the exactly code it should be here

                "Content-Security-Policy",
                "default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' data:;"
                        + "style-src 'self' fonts.googleapis.com 'sha256-CwE3Bg0VYQOIdNAkbB/Btdkhul49qZuwgNCMPgNY5zw=';" + "base-uri 'self' data:;"
                        + "frame-src 'self' * data:;" + "connect-src 'self' * data:;"
                        + "font-src 'self' fonts.gstatic.com https://cdn.predix-ui.com data:;"
                        + "frame-ancestors 'self' data:");

Answer (score 0):

The error messages includes the script-src directive "script-src 'self' 'nonce-Njg3MGUxNzkyMjViNDZkN2I3YTM3MDAzY2M0MjUxZGEzZmFhNDU0OGZjNDExMWU5OTVmMmMwMTg4NTA3ZmY4OQ=='", while there is no script-src directive in your configured policy. As it is lacking it should use the fallback to default-src, which should allow 'unsafe-inline'. Either you changed the policy in the meantime, or you have multiple policies defined.

The error message says that there is an inline event handler (onclick, onchange etc). These can be allowed with a hash and 'unsafe-hashes' in CSP level 3, but the best solution is to rewrite them with an event listener.

For XSS, you should be most concerned about restricting script-src. XSS through styles is really hard if you restrict the rest of your CSP, see https://scotthelme.co.uk/can-you-get-pwned-with-css/.